# Why is Docker removing the double quotes from my environment variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

When I build my docker image and run the container, the double quotes are removed from my environment variable.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/logs

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Timezone
ENV TZ America/Chicago

### Edges
ENV MONITORING_EDGE_THRESHOLDS={"onlineStatus":"OFFLINE","processors":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"memory":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"disks":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"subsystems":{"critical":200,"degraded":100},"networks":{"critical":2,"degraded":1}}

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Docker inspect shows the quotes are removed:

```
MONITORING_EDGE_THRESHOLDS

{onlineStatus:OFFLINE,processors:{critical:90,degraded:75},memory:{critical:90,degraded:75},disks:{critical:90,degraded:75},subsystems:{critical:200,degraded:100},networks:{critical:2,degraded:1}}
```

Subsequently, my node.js app is failing because I need to convert this value to a JSON object using JSON.parse(), which isn't working because it's not a valid JSON object due to Docker removing the quotes.

Comment: presumably because env vars can be quoted, but then you have to escape any quotes inside, so `MONITORING_EDGE_THRESHOLDS="{\"onlineStatus\":\"OFFLINE\",\"........"` but why is this an env var instead of a file like `monitoring-prod.config.json` that you just read in?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". It's either JSON, i.e. *text*, or it is an object. Parsing JSON creates an object. Try not calling `JSON.parse()` on it but instead to simply access a property directly.

Comment: @Chris G, returns undefined. It is a string until it is converted to an object with `JSON.parse(string)`, which works fine when running on localhost using .env.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, would using single quotes work without escaping?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) say: `The value will be interpreted for other environment variables, so quote characters will be removed if they are not escaped.` I'm guessing just replace all `"` with `\"` in your original JSON and use that as value, no outside delimiters needed.

Comment: @Chis G, thanks - that's unfortunate. It's very ugly. I think I'm going to go the docker-compose route and read in the .env file instead of using Dockerfile for environment variables.

Comment: @Chris G, well pulling in the .env file behaves the same way. Back to the drawing board.. an env variable with escapes for special characters just so I can use JSON is project breaking.

Comment: Right, so what about loading a JSON file? This is what Mike suggested.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see Mike G's comment about loading in a JSON file.. That makes a lot of sense and will try it.

Comment: @Dshiz not if you want a universally supported value, no.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ENV MONITORING_EDGE_THRESHOLDS='{"onlineStatus":"OFFLINE","processors":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"memory":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"disks":{"critical":90,"degraded":75},"subsystems":{"critical":200,"degraded":100},"networks":{"critical":2,"degraded":1}}'
```

Comment: When trying to use it, with JSON.parse => `Unexpected token '`, without JSON.parse: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'critical' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Simply escaping double quotes should work:

```
ENV MONITORING_EDGE_THRESHOLDS={\"onlineStatus\":\"OFFLINE\",\"processors\":{\"critical\":90,\"degraded\":75},\"memory\":{\"critical\":90,\"degraded\":75},\"disks\":{\"critical\":90,\"degraded\":75},\"subsystems\":{\"critical\":200,\"degraded\":100},\"networks\":{\"critical\":2,\"degraded\":1}}
```